# C# Instances not existing in current context

Tags: c#

```
        Console.WriteLine("Are you a boy or a girl?");
        string sex = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(sex);
        while ((sex != ("boy")) && (sex != ("girl")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid sex. Please answer the question again.");
            sex = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        if (sex == "boy")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are a boy");
            Boy real_sex = new Boy
            {
                Firstname = "George",
                Secondname = "Smith"
            };
        }
        else if (sex == "girl")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are a girl");
            Girl real_sex = new Girl
            {
                Firstname = "Charlotte",
                Secondname = "Smith"
            };
        }

        real_sex.Characteristics()
```

I'm new to C# so this might be easy but I was trying to make a programme that asks for the user's sex and then creates an instance for the class based on the answer of "boy" or "girl." I have already created the method "Characteristics" inside the classes "Boy" and "Girl." However, the problem arises with the last line "real_sex.Characteristics()" as "real_sex" does not exist in "current context." Apparently, to overcome this with regular variables you need to declare the variable before the if statements but it seems with instances it acts differently. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Does the classes `Boy` and `Girl` both inherit from a base class or interface that has `Characteristics()` listed as a method on it?

Comment: Context is defined by curly bracers { }. Variable real_sex does not exit at the point where you want to access it.

Comment: You're declaring the real_sex variable in a nested scope. You won't be able to access it outside of that scope.

Comment: You mention a distinction between "regular variables" and "instances" (perhaps value vs reference types?). I think that's the result of a misunderstanding on your part, because it makes no sense to me. What do you see as different between the two with regard to this issue?

Comment: Post your complete code, how you created object and  what is access specifer of characteristics () method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. When you define a variable within a block of code, it will not exist outside of that block of code. For instance:

```
int a = 2;
{
    int b = 3;
}
Console.WriteLine("A : " + a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("B : " + b.ToString());
```

Would print A fine, but would throw an error trying to print B, because B was defined in a block of code that ended before the print statement.

The solution is to define variables you need in the same (or a higher) block of code than you need them. Compare:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 0;
{
    b = 3;
}
Console.WriteLine("A : " + a.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("B : " + b.ToString());
```

This will work fine, and now prints A : 2 and B : 3.

So, change

```
        if (sex == "boy")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are a boy");
            Boy real_sex = new Boy
            {
                Firstname = "George",
                Secondname = "Smith"
            };
        }
        else if (sex == "girl")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are a girl");
            Girl real_sex = new Girl
            {
                Firstname = "Charlotte",
                Secondname = "Smith"
            };
        }

        real_sex.Characteristics()
```

to

```
        Sex real_sex = null;
        if (sex == "boy")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are a boy");
            real_sex = new Boy
            {
                Firstname = "George",
                Secondname = "Smith"
            };
        }
        else if (sex == "girl")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are a girl");
            real_sex = new Girl
            {
                Firstname = "Charlotte",
                Secondname = "Smith"
            };
        }

        real_sex.Characteristics()
```

Of course, you will need a parent class called "Sex" from which Boy and Girl are derived, so that you can set real_sex to either Boy or Girl.

Comment: Or both need to implement a common interface that has `Characteristics()` in it and you can access both Boy and Girl over the interface ...

Comment: Yes, the best approach simply depends upon the specifics (e.g. if there were identical functions between the two, using a parent class would reduce duplicate code vs. an interface)

Answer (score 0):

```
You have escope problem.
You need to declara the variable outside the if statement.  

If (){

Code and variables that only exist here can only run here 
//This method have to run here

Real_Sex.Characteristics();
Have to run here
}
Else {
Same here...
}
Or you can make a dynamic variable outside the scope



Console.WriteLine("Are you a boy or a girl?"); string sex = Console.ReadLine();
            dynamic real_sex;
            Console.WriteLine(sex); 
        while ((sex != ("boy")) && (sex != ("girl"))) 
    { 
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid sex. Please answer the question again."); 
        sex = Console.ReadLine(); }
         if (sex == "boy") {
         Console.WriteLine("You are a boy");
          real_sex = new Boy 
        { Firstname = "George", 
    Secondname = "Smith" }; 
    } 
        else if(sex == "girl") 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("You are a girl"); 
             real_sex = new Girl
         { Firstname = "Charlotte", 
        Secondname = "Smith" }; 
    }
         real_sex.Characteristics();
```